# Dynamicaly Customize the UI of a User Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I want to change the position of elements in ASP.NET User Control UI dynamically based on a condition. For eg:-
Here is the Normal layout of my User Control[image]

Now I want to re position the Edit button as below based on a condition.
[image]

I can think of following approaches but not sure if they are good and best way to do this.

1. We can create a Button in the desired place of my user control and then Show that button based on this condition and hide the original button. So the user control will have Two buttons in the UI (one Inline and other in a new line). Based on my condition, I show or hide them respectively.
2. Create another User Control and use it.

But I guess for this small change its kind of overkill
Are there any best known methods/better solution out there to handle such kind than what I can think of
Any constructive input would help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two buttons, one button in the desired place of my user control and one in the target place. The first button will be displayed as block by default and the second button will be displayed as none by default. Depend on your condition you can change the class of the first button and second button to make the first one hidden and the second will be displayed as block. Here is an example :

In source :

```
<style>
    .HideButton {
        display: none;
    }

    .ShowButton {
        display: block;
    }
</style>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"  Text="Button" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button CssClass="HideButton" ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button />
                </td>
                <td">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>     
</form>
```

In code behind :

```
if (something)
            {
                Button1.CssClass = "HideButton";
                Button2.CssClass = "ShowButton";
            }
```

Another solution is to change the innerHTML of td tag as follow :

In source :

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    <td id="DesiredLocation" runat="server"><input type="button" value="button1" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="TargetLocation" runat="server"></td>
                    <td"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>     
    </form>
```

And in aspx code :

```
if (something)
            {
            TargetLocation.InnerHtml = DesiredLocation.InnerHtml;
            DesiredLocation.InnerHtml = "";
            }
```

Hope this work.

Comment: BTW the Dropdown and button I showed in my post are not in consecutive new lines, There are few hidden div's in there. Secondly, I just want to change the UI as described on an IF statement but not on an event.

Comment: The idea is the same. instead of event you can use if statement. I will update the answer.

Comment: :"You can use one button" Are you referring to Edit Button or a completely new one? if its a new one, then its similar to my approach 1 instead we are using styles, correct?  If its an existing one,how does this CSS figure out the target location of the existing button.

Comment: No just use one button. Don't create new one. The idea is simple. Use one button and based on condition you want change the position to the any position you want. Using the ID of element will make css able to find the element you want and add the style you want

Comment: Here Button is an element and the table cell where we need to place the button is the target location. we can add the styles to the element based on ID but how CSS shifts the button(element) from one position to another thats what is confusing me

Comment: Why you not say this in your question. This can save time for us. I will update the answer because here the scenario is different.

Comment: Sorry if I am not clear in my question. I am trying to reposition a button of my user control to a new location based on a condition. Apologies for wasting your time..:(

Comment: @Programmerzzz I update the answer once more time to show two methods that can be used. The first method is the same as you explain and the second is to use inerHTML.